# Regex to allow only numbers and a dash in a textfield

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a regex to allow the entry of just one dash in the string.

Example of allowed entry:

`0001`
`000-1`

Example of entry not allowed:

`0-0-1`

This works very well but allows the entry of several strokes.

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9-]+'))`

Then it changes to this one, but it is not allowed to enter traces, although I validated in the regexpal.

`FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('^([0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)?)'))`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Use `^[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?$`

Comment: Without result, I do not know what the rule for regex in flutter, I have tried several and nothing works.

Comment: @Chance You need to escape ``\`` in your string containing the regular expression. You can either use ``\\`` or mark the whole string as a raw string like: ``r'^([0-9]+(\-[0-9]+)?)'``.

Comment: You went wrong when you used the filtering regex, instead of the validator regex.  Consider that at every keystroke, your filtering regex MUST BE TRUE.  You could never type "123-" on the way to "123-45".  Solution: use validator.

Comment: Yes, I understood that later, my idea of validating during the entry is impossible, only in the validator.

Answer (score 0):

```
const entries = '''
0001
000-1
0-0-1
''';

void main() {
  var re = RegExp(r'^\d\d*-?\d*\d$', multiLine:true);
  var matches = re.allMatches(entries);
  
  matches.toList().forEach((m) => print(m.group(0)));
}
```

Result:

```
0001
000-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```dart
TextField(
 keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
 inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+(?:-\d+)?$')),
  ], 
),
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/S8Kxzs/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```